# How can I replace the elements of an array with absolute values instead? c#

Tags: c#, math

I'm given various arrays (so I can't use index). Is there a way to replace elements with absolute values of them instead so that I can get an absolute sum?
For example, can I use foreach statement to get absolute value of each element? If I can, then how?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: An `Array` (and `List<T>`) is always indexable - do you mean you're working with non-indexed collections or `IEnumerable<T>` instead?

Comment: Yes, they are indexiable. Though I'm given more than one array. So I can't just say replace myArr[-1] with Math.Abs(myArr[1]). It should be a common expression that works for multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Linq's `.Select` method to apply a *mapping transformation* to each element in an `IEnumerable<T>` (this includes `Int32[]` (aka `int[]`), `List<Int32>`, `List<int>`, `HashSet<Int32>`, etc).

```
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<Int32> numbers = ...

return numbers.Select( n => Math.Abs( n ) ).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to programming. Can you tell me what "n" stands for?

Comment: @HarunKüf `n` the name given to the Lambda Function parameter. It's arbitrary but it's common to use short names like `n` to represent **n**umbers, `i` to represent **i**ndexes or `s` for **s**trings. Unlike lambda-functions, member function parameters should always use clear and descriptive names because they're publicly exposed.

Comment: Also I don't know much about lambda expression. I'm a total wreck haha.

Comment: @HarunKüf Lambda’s are actually not that complicated. `n => Math.Abs(n)` is more or less the same as writing `int MyFunc(int n) { return Math.Abs(n); }`. What Select does is that it calls the provided method – here a lambda function which is just a method without a name – for every item and returns the result of the method instead of the list item.

Comment: @ckuri I couldn't find a video where it's explained as clearly as you did. That's why I love stackoverflow.